# How to setup a Goal

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have journey builder working fine and linked to DataExtensionA, now I need to stop the journey/exit during a contact in the journey when a particular field set to true in the  DataExtensionB.

How I can configure this? Do I need to add DataExtensionB to population as well?

DataExtensionA salesforceid do exist in DataExtensionB as well.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

Data Extension B will need to be included as an Attribute Set in an Attribute Group. Once it's done this, create a Goal that evaluates the boolean field in Data Extension B as the Contact Filter.

After the Contact Filter step, select the **Exit Option** 'When the customer reaches this goal, they will exit the Interaction'. This will cause Contacts to be ejected from the Journey when they reach the Goal.

FYI, Goals are evaluated:

1. Each time a contact is fired into a journey
2. Each time a wait period expires
3. Every day at midnight, Central Standard Time